How to get requested page (node.js)
I am currently working with Node.js servers. When I access the server, the following code executes:
res.write("Whatever text you choose");
For example, when I navigate to localhost:9090, I receive the expected file. However, if I try to access localhost:9090/index.html, localhost:9090/funnyFile/Jokes.html, or localhost:9090/myProjects/poj1/index.html, I still receive the same file. I would like to know how to configure the server to serve different files based on the URL path.
Here is the code for my Node.js server:
const http = require('express')
const port = 9090

// Create a server object:
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    // Write a response to the client
    res.write("I choose this text");
    

    // End the response 
    res.end()
})

// Set up our server so it will listen on the port
server.listen(port, function (error) {

    // Checking any error occur while listening on port
    if (error) {
        console.log('Something went wrong', error);
    }
    // Else sent message of listening
    else {
        console.log('Server is listening on port' + port);
    }
})


Well, YOU have to do that.  You need to define a set of "routes" that describe the requests you are willing to handle.  There's usually a way to have the server serve static files just by identifying the directory.

This question is similar to: How do you use several request handler in node.js?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Turns out I needed to install and require both fs and path (and use http instead of express). This works very well (unless you are importing something):
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, req.url);

    fs.stat(filePath, (err, stats) => {
        if (err || !stats.isFile()) {
            fs.readdir(__dirname, (err, files) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.statusCode = 500;
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
                    res.end('Internal Server Error');
                    return;
                }

                res.statusCode = 404;
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
                res.end(`This page can't be found. Available files:\n${files.join('\n')}`);
            });
            return;
        }

        fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);
    });
});

const port = 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});

Although I like the answer provided by M Z.

You imported express but you're not using it. http does not provide methods to serve static files/routing.
Instead, use express to handle these, like so:
const app = express();

// Serve static files from a directory (e.g. 'public')
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Define your routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Some welcome text.');
});

// Example with 'funnyFile' and 'myProject'
app.get('/funnyFile/Jokes.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'funnyFile', 'Jokes.html'));
});

app.get('/myProjects/poj1/index.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'myProjects', 'poj1', 'index.html'));
});


That is simple enough. I can do that.

You should define routes for those files by using app.use and get request by router.get, then when you request that route you will access it.


   const express = require("express");
   //router object
    const router = express.Router();
    
    //routes GET | POST |UPDATE | DELETE ==>CRUD
    router.get(".path or url", call back function);



